# how to update slave server it's delayed two weeks data compare with master server

Tags: mysql

I have master server which is running good and I have done replication to Slave server
when I configured It is working fine, after one day (from 4th June) slave not updating the data after two weeks I have done RESET SLAVE with current BIN LOG and LOG POS then slave start updating (from 19th June'12). Now I have loss 2 weeks data from 4th to 18th June how to I get the data. As I know by restoring the master we can do it however client not in a position to down the Master server. Please tell me how to get the two weeks data? and where to identify binary logs in Master server (Default location).

Comment: what does `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` say? is there any error message?

Comment: Slave_IO_State: waiting for master to send event

Answer (score 0):

this can be helpful to you .,

http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html

and you can find the binary logs location in the my.cnf file the MySQL server using .

Comment: I am unable to paste my show slave status there is not enough space

Comment: please any one help me on this